# Sqlite convert date to Unix Timestamp

Tags: sqlite

I have `Sqlite` database with table with date column, This column content a date values like `Fri Dec 01 18:54:58 GMT+02:00 2017` and i want to convert this values to `Unix timestamp`, I try to slove this issue using `strftime` function i get `null` value.

Any idea how to solve this issue with `Sqlite` without a programmer language?

The command has been used is `update Table set createDate=strftime('%s',createDate)*1000 where id=1`

[Sqlite Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: How did you use strftime, can you copy the command used and put it in the question? Thanks

Comment: refresh the page, updated.

Comment: Use a programming language that has support for parsing dates; this is not a job for SQLite.

Comment: As shown in the documentation you linked to, this is not one of the supported date formats.